# How to increment a for loop by more than 1?

Tags: php

How do I print a series like this?

6,15,24,33,42.....1000

I have tried using a for loop like this, but can't work out how to get it to increment by 9 on each iteration.

```
for($i = 6; $i <= 1000; $i = 9)
{
    echo $i . ', ';
}
```

Comment: Please make your question clearer.

Comment: None of the numbers you're showing in your series are prime, so why the code for a prime number?

Comment: Hum.. so it seems you want to start with 6 and add 9, is that?

Comment: it's a simple reiteration starts from 6 and prints every +9.. what is the problem? why our step is +1 ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quite simple really:-

```
for($i = 6; $i <= 1000; $i += 9){
    echo $i . ', ';
}
//If you have to finish the series with 1000, although it is not a part of the series:-
echo '1000';
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/eq1Gv)

Comment: You still have to output `1000` manually to make it complete.

Answer (score 11):

just for fun:

```
echo implode(', ', range(6, 1000, 9));
echo ", 1000";
```

Comment: I like this, good idea.

Comment: +1 for use of `range()` since it's easily overlooked ;)

Comment: Never knew `range()` existed. TIL something!

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
     for($i=6; $i<1000; $i+=9)
      echo $i."<br>";
?>
```

Seeing the question this can be an answer.

Comment: You still have to output `1000` manually to make it complete.